# How do I proxy_pass all traffic including websocket traffic to a port?

Tags: nginx

If traffic is websocket traffic I have to add

```
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

to my location block to get the websocket traffic to work. How do I make it so that all packets are forwarded to proxy_pass and websocket and regular traffic both work?

Comment: And what's not working now?

Comment: Websocket connections don't work unless I pass proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade" explicitly. Setting proxy_pass_request_headers      on; is not enough.

Comment: Just put all websockets into one `location` and set any header you want.

Comment: I'm forwarding traffic to a jupyter app, and I don't know all the endpoints that might be websockets. And what if an endpoint is sometimes websockets and sometimes http. Cannot there be one way to forward traffic without separating the websocket traffic?